# mongodb $geoIntersects query for all documents who's polygon contains a point. no results?

Tags: geojson, mongodb

I am trying to  find all documents for a point that is within a document's polygon.

using mongoTemplate to set up my geo index.

```
 mongoTemplate.indexOps(Boundary.class).ensureIndex(
        new GeospatialIndex("polygon"));
```

I have a Criteria2ds that extends Criteria:

```
public class Criteria2ds
 extends Criteria {

    private Map<String, Object> criteria = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    ...
    ...   
    public static Criteria2ds where(String key) {
        return new Criteria2ds(key);
    }
    public Criteria2ds intersects(Point point) {
        Assert.notNull(point);
        final ArrayList<Double> coordinates = new ArrayList<Double>();
        coordinates.add(point.getY());
        coordinates.add(point.getX());
        BasicDBObject geometry = new BasicDBObject()
            .append("type", "Point")
            .append("coordinates", coordinates);

        criteria.put("$geoIntersects", new BasicDBObject("$geometry", geometry));

        return this;
    }
```

my query:

```
Query   query = new Query();

query.addCriteria(Criteria2ds.where("polygon").intersects(point));
```

..
this creates the query:

```
    { "polygon" : { "$geoIntersects" : { "$geometry" : { "type" : "Point" , "coordinates" : [ -105.01621 , 39.57422]}}}}

Collection<MyDoc> list  =  mongoTemplate.find(query, Boundary.class)
```

however, the results are 0?

is there something wrong with my code?

```
public class MyDoc
       Polygon polygon;
       public Collection<Polygon> getPolygons() {
        return polygons;
    }

    public void setPolygons(Collection<Polygon> polygons) {
        this.polygons = polygons;
    }



public interface BoundaryRepository extends MongoRepository<Boundary, String>{
}
```

I save in a DAO like:

```
boundaryRepository.save(myDoc);
```

Comment: can I improve the question? :/

Comment: I think the problem here is there is no way for us to know whether or not the query is actually working correctly. For example, maybe your polygon really does intersect 0 points?